# how can the same function with the same parameters yield different answers in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code:

```
Sub testingstuff()
    Dim x, y As Long       
     x = Find_lastest_day_events("flurry_an_output.csv", "User_Session", 4)
     y = Find_lastest_day_events("flurry_an_output.csv", "User_Session", 4)
    Debug.Print "x is " & x
    Debug.Print "y is " & y
End Sub
```

Yields the following output in the Immediate Window:

```
x is 121
y is 0
```

How on earth is that possible???

Here is the function:

```
Function Find_lastest_day_events(sheet_name As String, event_name As String, event_col As Integer)

    '   find the range of the last full day in a column and count the number of events for the last day
    '   use '*' in event name to just count events in range
    Dim rows1 As Long
    rows1 = Get_Rows_Generic(sheet_name, 1) ' total rows in sheet
    Dim col1 As Integer
    col1 = Range(find_last_column(sheet_name)).column ' last column number [uses address first]

    Dim last_cell As Range
    Dim full_range As Range
    With Worksheets(sheet_name)
        Set last_cell = .Range(.Cells(rows1, col1), .Cells(rows1, col1)) ' sets last_cell to the last cell in the sheet
        Set full_range = .Range(.Cells(1, col1), .Cells(rows1, col1)) ' whole last column as range
    End With

    Dim todays_date As Long
    todays_date = Date

    Dim search_date As Long
    search_date = todays_date - 1 

    Dim first_position As Long
    first_position = WorksheetFunction.Match(search_date, full_range, 0) 

    Dim last_position As Long
    last_position = WorksheetFunction.Match(search_date, full_range, 1) 

    Dim event_range As Range
    With Worksheets(sheet_name)
        Set event_range = .Range(.Cells(first_position, event_col), .Cells(last_position, event_col)) ' set the range to be searched
    End With

    Dim event_count As Integer
    event_count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(event_range, event_name) '  count the numbe rof events

    Find_lastest_day_events = event_count
End Function
```

** added based on comments **

```
Function Get_Rows_Generic(work_sheet_get As String, column_num As Integer)
    Dim ws As Worksheet:             Set ws = Worksheets(work_sheet_get)
    Dim rows_count As Long:                 rows_count = ws.Cells(rows.Count, column_num).End(xlUp).Row
    Get_Rows_Generic = rows_count
End Function


Function find_last_column(ws_name As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets(ws_name)
    Set rng1 = ws.rows(1).Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    find_last_column = rng1.Address  ' returns the address of the first cell in the last column used as a string
End Function
```

Comment: What does `Get_Rows_Generic` do?

Comment: And `find_last_column`

Comment: Also, for fun, `dim` your `x` and `y` variables each on their own line and run it again. When you smash them into the same line only one will be properly typed, the other will be a variant. I don't think it would effect the code here, but since the function return type isn't declared, it may.

Comment: My guess is that you need to clear the `.Find` in your `find_last_column` function.  Try putting `ws.cells.find ("*")` before the `End Function`.  If that works, I will post an answer with explanation.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks, but it didn't work.  Still same problem.

Comment: OK. Then that's not it. Anyways, I ran your code and I get the same results eaach time I run it (IOW: I cannot replicate the discrepancy you have). You should *step through your code* and examine the values in the Locals window, or set a Watch on certain variables to see *when* they're diverging, then that will assist in identifying a root cause (and resolution).

Comment: Before you do that, though, you may want to close Excel and re-start. See if the discrepancy persists. Sometimes funky things happen to workbook, and restarting Excel (or rebooting) may resolve it.

Comment: @DavidZemens I restarted the whole machine (mac) and the issue still persists.  It's very, very odd.  that function works for many other parts of the code.  When, however, I copy the text of one particular function call, it doesn't work.  damnedest thing I've ever seen (in my very limited programming career).